# Make a table row field in a django template multi column

Tags: django

I have a template that includes all the HTML for a table on a form. I am using a generic form for my model.  My model looks like this:

```
    class Program(models.Model):
        air_date = models.DateField(default="0000-00-00")
        air_time = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
        service = models.CharField(max_length=10) 
        block_time = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
        running_time = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
        remaining_time = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        locked_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        deleted_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        library = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=255,blank=True)
        mc = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=64)
        producer = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=64)
        editor = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=64)
        remarks = models.TextField()
        audit_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
        audit_user = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=32)
```

The template form looks like this:

```
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <TABLE BORDER="0" TABLE_LAYOUT="fixed" WIDTH="100%">
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
      <TD ALIGN="Right">Program Title:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">{{ form.title }}</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Right">Library:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.library }}</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Right">Service Bureau:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.service }}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
      <TD ALIGN="Right">Program Id:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ program.pk }}</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Right">Air Date:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.air_date }}</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Right">Air Time</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.air_time }}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
      <TD ALIGN="Right">Producer:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.producer }}</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Right">Editor:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.editor }}</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Right">MC:</TD><TD ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.mc }}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
      <TD BGCOLOR="#99CCFF" ALIGN="Right">Duration:</TD>
          <TD BGCOLOR="#99CCFF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.block_time }}</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Right">Rem. Time:</TD>
          <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.remaining_time }}</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="Right">Run Time:</TD>
          <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ form.running_time }}</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="#15C1B5">
      <TD ALIGN="Right">Remarks:</TD><TD COLSPAN="5"><PRE>{{ form.remarks }}</PRE></TD>
      </TR>
</TABLE>
```

The table looks fine - but the remarks field itself is only about 45 characters across, and even though I see a grab point in the corner of the box, I cannot expand the window of the text area past the third column.  I want the field to be expandable, max to 60 - 70 characters.  See picture below:
[image: Scree picture]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `<textarea>` to create that box i think the issue is with the CSS for that textarea element, i noticed that bootstrap disables expanding textarea horizontally, so that might be the source of your problem.

Comment: So - Is there a way to override the bootstrap setting?

Comment: yah, change <textarea></textarea> to <textarea style="resize:both;"></textarea>

Comment: Hmmm..  not really using a textarea, although the base.html is using bootstrap code.

Comment: doesn't {{ form.remarks }} have html code in it? how else does that textarea exist in the picture

Comment: Yeah, the textarea gets generated by boot strap it appears.